# Find the adjacent sides of the quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry

The two adjacent sides of a cyclic quadrilateral are 2 and 5 and the angle between them is $60^0$. If the area of the quadrilateral is $4\sqrt3$, then remaining sides are.

a. 2 and 3

b. 3 and 4

c. 4 and 5

d. 5 and 6

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $d = \sqrt{2^2+5^2- 2\cdot 2\cdot 5\cos 60^{\circ}}$

Find the opposite angle: $\alpha =180^{\circ} - 60^{\circ} = ?$

Area of opposite triangle = $4\sqrt{3} - \dfrac{2\cdot 5\sin 60^{\circ}}{2}= S$

$d^2 = x^2+y^2-2xy\cos 120^{\circ}$

$S = \dfrac{xy\sin 120^{\circ}}{2}$.

Solve for $x,y$